# android studio vs eclipse android resources

Tags: android, resources

Есть ли в android studio помощник для создания ресурсов в xml такой как в eclipse android resources? Если да то как его открыть?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Нет, такого в студии нет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть. <минимум 30 символов для того, чтобы написать ответ, поэтому я пишу тут этот текст.>[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Да но он работает только ко с файлом string.xml и позволяет добавлять только строковые поля. А eclipse android resources позволяет добавлять разные типы. Цвет например.

Comment: @BogdanShulga, в студии все это делается по другому. Тут просто вписываешь ресурс, которого не существует, код подсвечивается ошибкой, нажимаешь alt+Enter, и тебе предлагается создать новый ресурс с таким именем и подходящего типа. Для меня это во много раз удобнее эклипсового редактора.